# Use CSW request to get DEM data that intersects with linestring

Tags: geoserver, csw

I have DEM data in tiff format, in a mosaic store published from GeoServer.

GeoServer have the CSW 2.0.2 service available.
I would like to query the DEM data via an CSW request to retrieve the height values that intersects a linestring(polyline).

How do I start or going about doing that?

I have looked at the OGC docs, but find is difficult to understand how to put a CSW request together.

Comment: A CSW is a catalog of data not for actual data. It sounds like you need a WPS process, and I don't think there's one prewritten to do that

Answer (score -1):

After further research it looks like CSW request would rather return datasets that will satisfy a filter in the request, and not the actual data in datasets.
So for my purposes the CSW protocol is not what I am looking for.

Comment: A CSW request doesn't return datasets, it returns metadata that describes datasets, services, reports etc